# Rename [windows-azure-*] to just [azure-*]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Due to [the renaming](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/25/upcoming-name-change-for-windows-azure/) Windows Azure to just Azure please rename all tags `[windows-azure-*]` to just `[azure-*]`, such as:

- [windows-azure-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage) 1599
- [windows-azure-queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-queues) 93
- [windows-azure-diagnostics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-diagnostics) 74
- [windows-azure-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-blob) 48
- [windows-azure-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-networking) 16
- [windows-azure-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-pack) 5

Another option is to rename them to `[microsoft-azure-*]` but is there any other "azure" to make such distinction?

The rest of the Azure-related tags are already named properly:

- [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) (Microsoft Azure itself)
- [azure-storage-blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage-blobs)
- [azure-web-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites)
- etc.

So it's a question of consistency.

Comment: Not a user, but I'd personally think [tag:microsoft-azure] is clearer.  It's not like it costs you all that much typing (and the un-microsofted could be made synonyms until/unless a different azure exists).

Comment: The product is called Windows Azure, so windows-azure is the appropriate tag name.

Comment: @Ray: have you visited the link in the top?

Comment: @abatishchev: Did you?  The post explicitly says the new name is "Microsoft Azure", not "just Azure"

Comment: @BenVoigt: we don't have [[tag:microsoft-.net]] (the official product name) but just [[tag:.net]].

Comment: There is no product "Microsoft .NET"  There's Visual Studio, .NET Framework, .NET Compact Framework, .NET Micro Framework, Silverlight, and so on.  All different products in the .NET family.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't think they are sure themselves: [Download Microsoft .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851), [Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx), [Affected Software: Microsoft .NET](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-oct), and so on.

Comment: The title of that first link is actually "Download Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0"  Last one also "Microsoft .NET Framework" in the affected software column.

Comment: Ok, you're right. So the product name is Microsoft .NET Framework, or just shortly .NET?

Comment: @RayNicholus Apparently they renamed in to Microsoft Azure in March 2014 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the perfect task for a moderator, who can simply rename tags with no disruption and no fuss. If it weren't for that, I'd have to agree with Ben Voigt and say it isn't worth the time and effort.

When it's simple and non-disruptive, consistency is a powerful argument. We now have consistency. All of the tags that I could find following the "windows-azure-*" pattern have been renamed to simply "azure-*". In other words, Cody boarded up all the Windows.

Synonym mappings were also created, just like [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure), which already had [windows-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure) as a synonym. I don't see the harm in this. It ensures that searches based on the synonyms (*e.g.*, for people who have them bookmarked) will continue to work, and it maximizes the chances that people will manage to find the appropriate tag for their questions.

Actually, as it turns out, in several cases, the "azure-*" tag already existed as a synonym. For example, [azure-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage) was a synonym of [windows-azure-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-azure-storage). On these, I just reversed the direction of the mapping, so that [azure-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage) is now the "master" tag.

I also cleaned up some other stuff surrounding the Azure tags, including synonyms and merges that had been proposed but not approved yet. If there's more that needs to be done to clean up the edges here, let me know. There are *so many* things named "Azure". It's like 2003, when ".NET" got attached to every product's name.

I was unsure about [microsoft-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-cognitive) and [azure-cognitive-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-services). A synonym was proposed for these, but I'm not sure if they are the same. The tag wikis are different. If they are the same, which one should be the "master" tag? In other words, what's the official name of the product?

Also, is [azure-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-hub) the same thing as [azure-iot-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-iot-hub)? I'm guessing it is, but don't feel comfortable doing things like this on a guess.

Comment: Just want to say huge thank you for your help! You're a super moderator!

Comment: Related discussion for the "cognitive" tags: [Make \[microsoft-cognitive\] synonym of \[azure-cognitive-services\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385333/1478931) – and subsequently included as part of this proposal: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)

Answer (score -9):

What's the point?

Are people active in these tags requesting this?
Is the existing tag somehow unclear or ambiguous?
Are we seeing questions not find the existing tag?

If the new names are useful, they'll start being used.  Then a synonym relationship can be set up.  No need to edit tag names.

Comment: If `[azure-*]` will be main tag and for responding `[windows-azure-*]` its synonym I'm fine with it.

Comment: And the point is in the **consistency**. See [[tag:azure]], [[tag:azure-web-roles]], etc. (40 more)