# Merge [az-application-insights] into [ms-application-insights]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can you please merge [az-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/az-application-insights) (267) into [ms-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-application-insights) (515)?

I also would rename it to just [application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-insights) if [azure-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insights) is too long.

Comment: can we create synonyms? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insight

Comment: @Arun synonyms system is broken and doesn't seem anybody cares, for many years now

Comment: thats bad. one more dupe tag added 'azure-application-insight'

Comment: @ArunVinoth: Please post your edit as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag names can be long now—[up to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490)—so [azure-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insights) is clearly the best name for the tag. I've mashed buttons such that it is now the *master* tag.

[az-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/az-application-insights) and [ms-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-application-insights) were merged into [azure-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insights), and the former two tags are now synonyms of the latter. I also manually merged in the content from the tag wikis. Still reads kinda like it was copied from some Microsoft marketing material, though, and would benefit from an expert's attention.

Arun Vinoth had proposed a synonym for [azure-application-insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insight) (*i.e.*, the non-plural form). That had 13 questions to its name, so I merged that tag into the master [azure-application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-application-insights), but did not create a synonym. (Synonyms are really only useful for making sure that people enter the right tag when composing a question, and when the plural form exists, no one is going to manually enter the singular form.) The non-plural form of the tag should be gone from the system entirely now, save for caching effects.

The [application-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-insights) tag still does not exist, because it's not a good name for a tag.

Comment: Can you please also take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273248/rename-windows-azure-to-just-azure?

Answer (score 2):

Created a new [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-application-insights/synonyms) suggestion to merge. It helps MS PG team to resolve/respond to community without miss.