# Make [microsoft-cognitive] synonym of [azure-cognitive-services]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[microsoft-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-cognitive) has over 1k questions;
[azure-cognitive-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-services) has over 400 questions

They really seem to refer to the same thing to me, and tend to be very highly correlated.

I'd tend to favor [azure-cognitive-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-services) over the other tag, even if it's not the largest tag, because Cognitive Services are an Azure-branded product.

Comment: This merger + synonym is now complete, as of a more recent (and broader) proposal that includes this suggestion: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)